# Disable highlight on applications that needs attention in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How do I disable the annoying yellow color of applications that needs attention in Windows 7.
An example would be the Firefox download, every time I download, the icon on the Taskbar always blinks with the yellow color until I click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox specifically it would probably suffice to get rid of the Downloads window. [This](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/26) Add-on is actually pretty nice, imho.

Generally I don't think you can completely turn it off. You can change how often it blinks at

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundFlashCount
```

However, setting a new value there only takes effect after re-logon. A value of 0 means “blink forever”. So the lowest one you can probably reasonably use is 1.